# How can I configure a Galaxy S4 to allow me to touch Dashclock to open items?

Tags: applications, lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-s-4, dashclock-widget

How can I configure a Galaxy S4 to allow me to touch Dashclock to open items?

I want to be able to tap on the email icon to open email, etc.  Dashclock appears to support this (I may be incorrect here?) but the S4 insists on making me swipe to unlock whenever I try to tap the email icon.

Comment: Why do you say that DashClock appears to support it? Is it in their Description?

Comment: When I tap the icons they light up as if something is supposed to happen but instead the S4 lock screen shows "Slide to unlock".

Comment: I am interested in a solution too. In this Video you can see that it is possible to unlock the screen when anything is touched: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfYvt8oc94w&feature=player_detailpage#t=144
But maybe it's a feature of the Galaxy S3?!